# How to use a ScrollView with a dynamic LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I'm trying to create an Activity with multiple items, one of them is a LinearLayout that is populated with other views on runtime.

My Activity XML for this purpose is like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context="com.ibosca.thub.QuestionResultsActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/questionIcon"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_help_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questionIcon"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/responses"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questionText"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm using this Java code to populate the Responses `LinearLayoutCompat`:

```
    LinearLayoutCompat rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.responses);

    ArrayList<Response> orderedresponses = question.getOrderedResponses();

    for (int i = 0; i < orderedresponses.size(); i++){

        currentResponse = orderedresponses.get(i);

        if(i == 0){
            nextResponse = orderedresponses.get(i+1);
        }

        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.response, null);

        TextView responseText = child.findViewById(R.id.responseText);
        TextView votesText = child.findViewById(R.id.votesText);

        responseText.setText(currentResponse.getText());
        String votesInfo = getResources().getString(R.string.votesPercentQuestionResult, Integer.toString(currentResponse.getVotes()) , Float.toString(currentResponse.getPercentVote()));
        //votesText.setText(currentResponse.getVotes() + " vots · " + currentResponse.getPercentVote() +"%");
        votesText.setText(votesInfo);

        if(i == 0 && currentResponse.getVotes() != 0 && nextResponse.getVotes() < currentResponse.getVotes()){
            //Set star icon
            ImageView icon = child.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_stars_black_24dp));

        }

        rootLayout.addView(child);

    }
```

And, the Response XML used in last piece of code looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

    <ImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_comment_black_24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/responseText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight=".90"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/votesText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="23dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_weight=".90"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/responseText" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

In my attempts, I realized that after Response's LinearLayoutCompat there are a blank extra space, that is causing a scroll when actually scroll is not needed.

I am unable to figure out where this space come from, but seems that this blank space grows up with the responses LinearLayout, so when the content inside on responses linear layout is small, blank space is small, and as it grows, blank space grows as well.

My goal is to remove this extra blank space, and having a scroll view only when it is needed, that is, when the linear layout is bigger tan the screens size.

How can I fix it?

**EDIT: SCREENSHOT OF THE PROBLEM**

[image: View fits perfectly on the screen, no extra space needed]

[image: Blank space before last element of the linear layout]

As you can see on first screenshot, the content fits on the screen, but android is adding extra space at the bottom of linear layout causing a estrange blank space.

Answer (score 0):

Edit or delete these lines in your .xml file and your problem will be solved:

```
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
Can you specify where should I remove this lines? These lines appears in more that one place on my XMLs.

Comment: Your welcome, we use margin for making space between things, So you should edit or delete the margins based on your need, for example here, you can delete margin at ImageView and TextView

Comment: I think this is a misunderstood. The blank space is at the bottom of the linear layout, not between the elements, so I think that this margin constraints are not the problem. I'll attach an image as edit to clarify this.

Comment: Yes after seeing your screen shots I understand what exactly happened,  I don't know what is the problem either, but I thinking maybe problem solved with changing height of the ConstraintLayout and ScrollView, Did you tried to change wrap_content with match_parent ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your root layout
2. Change `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `android:layout_height="match_parent"` in your ScrollView
3. Add `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` to your LinearLayoutCompat

Here's the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ibosca.thub.QuestionResultsActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/questionIcon"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_help_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questionIcon"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/responses"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questionText"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved issue myself.

I used the Android Studio Layout Inspector to see exactly what piece of my layout was taking more space than needed. You can find out more info within the docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html#open_the_layout_inspector

The problem was on the constraintLayout, so I tried to change the constraint layout to linearLayout and this solved the issue.

This is the final code:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.ibosca.thub.QuestionResultsActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/questionIcon"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_help_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/questionText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questionIcon"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.02" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:id="@+id/responses"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/questionText"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </ScrollView>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope this helps other people with similar problems!